# How to pass props values to react custom web components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please help use to resolve this case

**Parent component**

```
const HelloMessage = (props) => {  
  return <>
    <div className="main-counter" >
      <top-destination name="srini" />
    </div>
  </>
}
export default HelloMessage
customElements.define("react-counter", reactToWebComponent(HelloMessage, React, ReactDOM));
```

**Child (Web component)**

```
import React from 'react';
import reactToWebComponent from "react-to-webcomponent";
const TopDestination = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
  return <>
 <div>{props.name}</div> 
</>
}
export default TopDestination
customElements.define("top-destination", reactToWebComponent(TopDestination, React, ReactDOM));
```

[console log value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1xUL.png)

Answer (score 0):

In html

```
<top-destination name="John" />
```

Comment: I'm passing as same, you can see my parent component

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-check your Node version, It should be `Node 14 or above`.

Cross-check your `import ReactDom` statement, based on the React version you are using.

Update to the latest version of react-to-webcomponent and prop-types

Your code should be like this:

**Parent component**

```
import React from 'react';

const HelloMessage = (props) => {  
  return <>
    <div className="main-counter" >
      <top-destination name="srini" />
    </div>
  </>
}
export default HelloMessage
customElements.define("react-counter", reactToWebComponent(HelloMessage, React, ReactDOM));
```

**Child (Web component)**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import reactToWebComponent from "react-to-webcomponent"

const TopDestination = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
  return <>
 <div>{props.name}</div> 
</>
}

TopDestination.propTypes = {
     name: PropTypes.string,
}
customElements.define("top-destination", reactToWebComponent(TopDestination, React, ReactDOM));
export default TopDestination


// Other ways of defining the props if you are on better versions.

// customElements.define(
//     "top-destination",
//     reactToWebComponent(TopDestination, React, ReactDOM, {
//       props: {
//         name: String
//       },
//     }),
//   )


// or

//  customElements.define(
//    "top-destination",
//    reactToWebComponent(TopDestination, React, ReactDOM, {
//      props: ["name"]
//    }),
//  )
```

Refer this repo: https://github.com/sarat9/cross-ui-web-comp

File: https://github.com/sarat9/cross-ui-web-comp/blob/master/react-web-components/src/web-components/FancyButtonWC.js